# putting javascript after </html> tag

Tags: javascript, seo, joomla1.5

gtmetrix showing me to defer parsing of javascript for SEO Purpose of my website

for that i searched the forums, google etc., then i got that it should be placed after  tag in my template head.php file

but if i cut and paste any javascript file call to head.php file and if i unpublished that specific module then also it will load or not?

and there are many javascript files in modules which are loading on specific condition checking and if i put that files by default in head.php, will it cause any problem?

and i'm using joomla 1.5 framework

Please help me, i'm stucking on this problems since many days but not getting proper solution.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: can you apport some links at the information you are mentioning?

Comment: my domain is www.babacomputers.com and you can test it at gtmetrix.com and in that see first option as "DEFER PARSING OF JAVASCRIPT"

Comment: You can put your JavaScript files right before `</body></html>` to ensure the DOM is loaded before the files are downloaded and parsed. However, ***nothing*** should go after `</html>`. That is ***completely invalid*** markup.

Answer (score 1):

SEO crawlers don't care about where you place your javascript. It always looks trough the whole page for information. Lots of people add javascript in the head so it's located in the same place.

The best place for putting javascript is at the end of file, because of the users that visit your page. Browser can render your page while javascript is still not needed(most of the pages). Also javascript should be put in its own file, because browser can cache .js file request. That way your page loads faster and uses less bandwidth.

Comment: ya i know that but as gtmetrix.com showing me to place it at end but the problem is that my website developed in joomla 1.5, so as there are different modules, components, plugins installed using joomla framework, i can't cut call to javascript files from specific modules or plugins and place them by default at end of html tag in template main file(like default.php in joomla) , so i'm not getting how to solve that?............hope will get answer.....

Comment: Just to note. I analyzed it with google page speed. The problem is with the speed of the page, not SEO! You have main js file that is 600k minified. You should use joomla plugin for only loading js where it is needed.

Comment: can you please tell me the plugin please,

Comment: and actually, i added script merrge plugin to my website,

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SEO crawlers not cares about where your JS and other service code placed. They looking at time to last byte of the .html.
BUT! After crawling, your data learning by google filters, that checking links, texts and can check performance. Also they сan check "load completed" and "document ready" times. 
Defer load can help your SEO, but I really not tested it.
New Wordpress CMS uses this tactic.